# django wsgi correct configuration on vhosts

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I want put my working application on apache2 vhosts (Ubuntu), other hosts with php works ok but my problem is with django. I have 500 Internal
/home/py/django/kitty/kitty/wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/s/py/django/kitty')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "kitty.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/wiersze.td.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName  wiersze.td
#DocumentRoot /
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/s/py/django/kitty/kitty/wsgi.py
Alias /adminmedia/  /opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
<Directory "/home/s/py/django/kitty/kitty/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and in error.log

```
...
ImportError: Could not import settings 'kitty.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named kitty.settings
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In you `wsgi.py` you are importing `kitty.settings` those are not on your python path.

1. Edit your wsgi.py the following way:

   path = '/path/to/kitty'
   if path not in sys.path:
       sys.path.append(path)

see also:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/modwsgi/